# DevExpress WebChartControl Pie Controlling Fill

Tags: devexpress, pie-chart, webchartcontrol

I have been using the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting pie chart control to display pie chart.
With the introduction of IE9, these graphs seem intermittantly to not load and just present the user with an image not found.
I have decided to replace this with DevExpress's WebChartControl and implement their Pie Chart.

I got their pie to resemble ours 90%, but am stuck at getting the pie's fill to match.
This is best explained with images.

Here is my original MS Chart Pie:

[image: OLD MS Pie]

Here is my new Dev Express Pie:

[image]

The old pie seems to have a shadow effect around the border that makes it look much better.
Is this kind of effect possible with the DevExpress control?
I have tried playing with:

```
((PieSeriesView) series.View).Border
((PieSeriesView) series.View).FillStyle
```

Both don't seem to do what i want.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I tried for about an hour to get the desired result for you, but unfortunately I just can't seem to be able to get deep enough to be able to introduce a new painter with the Drawing2d.PathGradientBrush.Blend option (which would be able to give you the desired look).

I have placed a question on your behalf on the support center [Q337316](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q337316.aspx), you are welcomed to track this question which I would imagine will turn into a suggestion.

So although this isn't a good answer, I don't think you will be able to achieve the results in the current DX library.

Comment: Thanks you for time and effort to resolve my problem. I did post a question a few days later Q337148 and they confirmed it can't be done. Any suggestions to make the pie look nicer if not the same as i intended. Unfortunately i can't use the 3D version as i need to drill down.

Comment: Other than just using the default gradient to get the "lighten" look, I can't another way at the moment, however will see what DX come back with as we might be able to somehow trick the FillStyle.Options within the CustomDrawSeries event.

Answer (score 1):

We have answered this question in the [RadialGradientPainter - Support PathGradientBrush.Blend](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q337316) thread.  I've also talked to guys from the XtraCharts team.  This is impossible to implement in WindowsForms Charts, but should be possible in WPF.  If you are interested in this alternative, drop me a line and I will add the required information here.

Comment: Thanks for you response. This is for a web based solution so WPF is not an option. We are also not utilising Silverlight so that would not be an option either. I think support for Drill Down in 3D charts would be the best solution as the 3D chart looks great

Comment: Thx to DX for not only responding to the Support Center ticket but also on StackOverflow, just another example of DX's great support ;) (just a pity we can't achieve what we want :))